# Regular expression find group match in quotes

Tags: c#, regex, expression

I am struggling to find the group of text in single quote using regular expression. I would need your advice on how to get it.

Input text:

```
Transfer assignee from 'David, Patricia' to ''
Transfer group from 'Science Department - Support Group' to 'Science Department - Human Resources '
```

Requirement: I need to extract the group from and group to in the single quote and save it in database.

I tried but I always got empty result. Here is the code

```
 public void ExtractGroup(string text)
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(text, @" group from '([^']*)" to '([^']*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        if(match.Success) {
             var groupfrom = match.Groups[1].Value;
             var groupTo = match.Groups[2].Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have written a double quote instead of a single quote before `to` in your pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and I found that it is working fine:

```
public static void ExtractGroup()
{
    string input = "Transfer assignee from 'David, Patricia' to '' Transfer group from 'Science Department - Support Group' to 'Science Department - Human Resources '";
    var match = Regex.Match(input, @" group from '(?<from>[^']*)' to '(?<to>[^']*)'", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["from"]); // Science Department - Support Group
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["to"]); // Science Department - Human Resources
    }            
}
```

However, I run it in a C# Console application. But I don't think it will make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Given this input:

```
Transfer assignee from 'David, Patricia' to '' Transfer group from 'Science Department - Support Group' to 'Science Department - Human Resources '
```

And given your description:

```
 to extract the group from and group to in the single quote
```

You expect the output to be these two strings:

```
Science Department - Support Group
Science Department - Human Resources
```

I'd expect a regex like this would work:

```
 to .*?'(.*?)' to '(.*?)'
```

But, I'd probably make this a bit more complete as you may want the entire data set later:

```
Transfer (.*?) from '(.*?)' to '(.*?)' Transfer (.*?) from '(.*?)' to '(.*?)'
```

That way you get:

```
1: transfer type 1 - 'assignee'
2: transfer from 1 - 'David, Patricia'
3: transfer to 1   - ''
4: transfer type 2 - 'group'
5: transfer from 2 - 'Science Department - Support Group'
6: transfer to 2   - 'Science Department - Human Resources '
```

Alternatively you could abstract this out a bit by using the `Transfer (.*?) from '(.*?)' to '(.*?)'` regex and apply it to the string multiple times until the transfer type equals `group`.  This way you could later add logic for other transfer types, and you string could declare any number of transfers in it without anything breaking.